# Allow timestamp published/updated dates for certains fields?

Tags: entities, datetime

Is there a module to enable or disable the created and updated dates to certain fields?

The goal is to have a timestamp of the date of creation/modification date of a field (of type text) has multiple values.

Comment: I don't think anyone implemented that. For the same purpose I've seen people using simply many nodes (one per text) and views or reference field to aggregate them. Publishing and modified date works for nodes all right, so why not just use it?

Comment: Hi, if I understand your answer, goal is to create additional content types?

Comment: It's not an answer, merely a suggestion to go totally different way (that's why it's only a comment). But yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Ok, good, thank you for your reply. another solution can be create a fields collection that contain original field (you want make "timestampable") and a Date field type "published at"...